# How to cite a website?

Tags: citing

It is a firm's website. So I don't know the author. And I don't know when it is published. Usually, a paper is cited like author (year), but how shall I deal with this? I am using `\bibliographystyle{chicagoa}`.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Is it essential for you to use `chicagoa` style? This was last updated in 1992 (!) and supposedly supports the 13th edition of the CMOS. CMOS is now up to the 17th edition and life is much easier (unless this is to be submitted to a journal that specifies `chicagoa`)  if you use `biblatex` and `biblatex-chicago` style.

Answer (score 4):

The CMOS website has this to say about citing websites in author-date style:

> ## Website content
>
> It is often sufficient simply to describe web pages and other website content in the text (“As of May 1, 2017, Yale’s home page listed . . .”). If a more formal citation is needed, it may be styled like the examples below. For a source that does not list a date of publication or revision, use n.d. (for “no date”) in place of the year and include an access date.
>
> ### Reference list entries (in alphabetical order)
>
> Bouman, Katie. 2016. “How to Take a Picture of a Black Hole.” Filmed November 2016 at TEDxBeaconStreet, Brookline, MA. Video, 12:51. https://www.ted.com/talks/katie_bouman_what_does_a_black_hole_look_like.
>
> Google. 2017. “Privacy Policy.” Privacy & Terms. Last modified April 17, 2017. https://www.google.com/policies/privacy/.
>
> Yale University. n.d. “About Yale: Yale Facts.” Accessed May 1, 2017. https://www.yale.edu/about-yale/yale-facts.
>
> In-text citations
> (Bouman 2016)
>
> (Google 2017)
>
> (Yale University, n.d.)
>
> For more examples, see 15.50–52 in The Chicago Manual of Style. For multimedia, including live performances, see 15.57.

If you want to use `chicagoa.bst` without any modifications, then you can do something like:

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@misc{yale,
  author = {{Yale University}},
  year = {n.d.},
  title = {About {Yale}: Yale Facts},
  note = {Accessed May 1, 2017.  \url{https://www.yale.edu/about-yale/yale-facts}}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{chicago}
\usepackage{url}
\urlstyle{same}

\begin{document}

\citeN{yale} lorem ipsum

\bibliographystyle{chicagoa}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

[image: output from chicagoa]

---

To my mind, this is a bit average on a number of levels and certainly doesn't match what CMOS wants.

Unless I absolutely had to, I would not use `bibtex` for Chicago style, and instead use `biblatex` with `biber`:

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@online{yale,
  author = {{Yale University}},
  title = {About {Yale}},
  subtitle = {Yale Facts},
  urldate = {2017-05-01},
  url = {https://www.yale.edu/about-yale/yale-facts}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[authordate]{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\textcite{yale} lorem ipsum

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image: output with biblatex-chicago]

---

Comment: That makes sense. I can use the phrase in that document to avoid a formal citation. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to have the link address in a hyperlinked, monospaced font?

Comment: @ApoorvPotnis, the Chicago manual of style uses Roman font for URLs. Adding a hyperlink can be done using the hyperref package, but not directly relevant to the question